# How do I cast a variable in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given a variable with type `Graphics`, 
how do I cast it to `Graphics2D` in Scala?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

The preferred technique is to use pattern matching.  This allows you to gracefully handle the case that the value in question is *not* of the given type:

```
g match {
  case g2: Graphics2D => g2
  case _ => throw new ClassCastException
}
```

This block replicates the semantics of the `asInstanceOf[Graphics2D]` method, but with greater flexibility.  For example, you could provide different branches for various types, effectively performing multiple conditional casts at the same time.  Finally, you don't *really* need to throw an exception in the catch-all area, you could also return `null` (or preferably, `None`), or you could enter some fallback branch which works without `Graphics2D`.

In short, this is really the way to go.  It's a little more syntactically bulky than `asInstanceOf`, but the added flexibility is almost always worth it.

Comment: +1 because it's interesting, but a bit too much for this scenario. isn't it?

Comment: what if I already patternmatched but lost reference to the casted value: <code>base match { case MyConcrete(value) => base.asInstanceOf[MyConcrete].something(value) } </code>, is there a way to get 'base' casted to MyConcrete even if want to extract "value" by exploiting the 'unapply' call performed by "case MyConcrete(value)" ?

Comment: Try this: `base match { case base @ MyConcrete(value) => base.something(value) }`  Obviously, shadowing `base` is optional.  You could just as easily use a different variable name.

Comment: What I don't get is how would you get the result of this pattern matching cast into a variable? like in java if it was String a = (String) b; what would the scala equivalent be?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon `val gResult = g match {
  case g2: Graphics2D => g2
  case _ => throw new ClassCastException
}`

Comment: Why for casting only, they make it this complicated when in Java it is very easy?

Answer (score 227):

```
g.asInstanceOf[Graphics2D];
```

Comment: Once I got used to Scala, I learnt not to use `asInstanceOf`, since it defeats the purpose of having static type system and feels yucky.

Comment: Unfortunately, this a common operation when using Swing. For custom painting operations, you need to override the 'public void paintComponent(Graphics g)' method. The Graphics parameter is actually a Graphics2D instance, but a cast is needed. The pattern matching version is probably more verbosity than warranted. Remember: Sedulously eschew obfuscatory hyperverbosity and prolixity!

Comment: @hohonuuli I think the cast is fine in that specific case, but if you use `scala-swing` components, paintComponent's parameter is already Graphics2D so no cast required

Comment: Why its so long? Why "asInstanceOf when can be only be "as" or "asof" keyword or method? Or why they did not just adopt the C++ and Java way as an option because that is the conventional and there is no big problem with that?

Comment: @LemuelAdane The fact that you're using casts at all is a code smell, it makes no sense to make them easier.