# Is there Scala equivalent of C# "as" keyword?

Tags: c#, scala, casting, classcastexception

Is there Scala equivalent of C# `as` keyword?

```
var something = obj as MyClass;
```

Scala's `asInstanceOf` throws `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```
val something = obj.asInstanceOf[MyClass]
```

Comment: You should post the code that throws a ClassCastException. The object you're trying to cast simply isn't of that type.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931463/scala-how-do-i-cast-a-variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading up on C# a bit, I realized you probably meant this:

```
val foo = if (bar.isInstaceOf[Foo]) bar.asInstanceOf[Foo] else null.asInstanceOf[Foo]
```

It should be noted that using null is discouraged in Scala. You should really do this:

```
val foo = if (bar.isInstaceOf[Foo]) Some(bar.asInstanceOf[Foo]) else None
```

Comment: It should be noted too that casting in discouraged in Scala ;)

Comment: @Alois: Of course it is, but you can't write something equivalent to C#'s `as` without it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use pattern matching, like explained here: [How do I cast a variable in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931463/scala-how-do-i-cast-a-variable)