# How to cast Long to Int in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, casting, int, long-integer

I'd like to use the folowing function to convert from Joda Time to Unix timestamp:

```
def toUnixTimeStamp(dt : DateTime) : Int = {
  val millis = dt.getMillis
  val seconds = if(millis % 1000 == 0) millis / 1000
    else { throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Too precise timestamp") }

  if (seconds > 2147483647) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Timestamp out of range")
  }

  seconds
}
```

Time values I intend to get are never expected to be millisecond-precise, they are second-precise UTC by contract and are to be further stored (in a MySQL DB) as Int, standard Unix timestamps are our company standard for time records. But Joda Time only provides getMillis and not getSeconds, so I have to get a Long millisecond-precise timestamp and divide it by 1000 to produce a standard Unix timestamp.

And I am stuck making Scala to make an Int out of a Long value. How to do such a cast?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931463/scala-how-do-i-cast-a-variable

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use the `.toInt` method on Long, i.e. `seconds.toInt`

Comment: `.toInt` is better than `asInstanceOf[Int]`. what was I thinking.

Comment: Looks like it works. Compiles at least. Perhaps I need to have some sleep... :-]

Comment: @eugene-yokota, would you be so kind to explain why is .toInt better than asInstanceOf[Int]? Intuitively it seems obvious, but I am curious to know.

Comment: @Ivan, because `toInt` is still within the means of Scala standard library (and hopefully with good optimizations and checking etc) whereas `asInstanceOf` is like opening the emergency escape hatch while the plane is in midair.

Comment: @Ivan casts are inherently not typesafe. E.g. `class Foo; (new Foo).asInstanceOf[Int]` compiles, but throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime. So using a cast, you're losing the benefit of static type checking at compile time.

Comment: Yes, but is it efficient, or does it box?

Comment: @ScottCarey yes it is efficient. These enrichments (RichLong etc) are value classes, so effectively you're using a static method. You can rely on the Scala library writers to have thought of this kind of thing.

Comment: Does it throw an exception for values bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE? Something like guava's Ints.checkedCast(long) ? - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#checkedCast(long)

Comment: @raisercostin No it does not. In that respect it follows all other Java arithmetic, i.e. bounds-checking is sacrificed for performance. However it's trivial to write such a method yourself.