# Scala short and type safe cast operator

Tags: scala

I don't like Scala isInstanceOf and asInstanceOf methods - they are long and asInstanceOf can throw exception so we need to use it in couple. Better way is to use  pattern matching: [Scala: How do I cast a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931463/scala-how-do-i-cast-a-variable) but for really simple operations it can be relatively long too. In C# we have  'is' and 'as' operators so I wanted to implement implicit definition with this in Scala. My code look like this:

```
scala> class TypeCast(x:Any){
     | def is[T](t:Class[T]) = t.isInstance(x) 
     | def as[T](t:Class[T]):Option[T] = if(t.isInstance(x)) Option(t.cast(x)) else None
     | }
defined class TypeCast

scala> implicit def TypeCastID(x:Any)=new TypeCast(x)
TypeCastID: (x: Any)TypeCast

scala>  123 as classOf[String]
res14: Option[String] = None

scala> "asd" as classOf[String]
res15: Option[String] = Some(asd)
```

It has one advantage - implement null-object pattern but also have disadvantages:

- need to use classOf[T] operator - it's too long
- overhead connected with implicit def for such simple operation

so there is no practical reason to use it. 
I would like to know is there any way to implement this without need to use classOf[T]?

Comment: In my opinion, it is good that `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` have relatively long and inconvenient names. Normally you'll want to avoid dynamic type checking and casting and use a better OO-style approach instead (polymorphism) or pattern matching (functional style). The inconvenient names encourage you to not use them too much. In your title you're asking for a "type safe cast operator". Casting is never type safe, by definition.

Comment: I supposed that there will be similar comment. In general I agree with you that good design and pattern matching is much better. But sometimes IMHO 'as' notation is a lot shorter and clearer. For example we can use third party library where design is not as good as we need. It also return Option[T]  instead T so it's safer.  And at the end: answer to this question most of all give me additional knowledge about Scala :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you could shorten it down inside the def you made in the TypeCast class. So instead of feeding it a parameter you could just rely on the type. This would shorten it down a lot. As an example this could look something like:

```
class TypeCast(x : Any) {
    def is[T : Manifest] = manifest.erasure.isInstance(x)
    def as[T : Manifest] : Option[T] = if (manifest.erasure.isInstance(x)) Some(x.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
}
```

Future calls could look like:

```
scala> 123.as[String]
res0: Option[String] = Some(123)
scala> class A; class B extends A
defined class A
defined class B
scala> new B
res1: B
scala> res1.is[Int]
res2: Boolean = false
scala> res1.as[Int]
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Update: I added Manifests to avoid type-check errors

Comment: I try similar solution, but this unfortunatly not working correctly: class A; 
class B extends A; 
val b= new B; 
b.as[Int] give mi Some(instance-of-B) instead of None
and also b.is[Int] return true

Comment: It seems you can use manifests to clear things up.. I'll update the code.

Comment: Thanks! I never heard about Manifests before.

Comment: @theres Did you know the casting operators were made to _discourage_ casting ?

Comment: So, is this a **recommended** way to cast types in Scala?

Comment: As @AndreasScheinert pointed out casting really should be avoided. The native scala method is ``.asInstanceOf[X]`` where ``X`` is the desired type. I would really recommend using [Case matching](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120)

Comment: This doesn't work for boxed types. 1.is[Int] is false, because 1 is int :)

Comment: @JensEgholm could you please update the answer for scala 2.13 & 3?