# Java Listener interface to Scala

Tags: java, scala, interface

I have this kind of Java source code with a Listener.

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Send the event to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(position);
    }
}
```

And I implement it in this way:

```
public class MyActivity implements FragmentA.OnArticleSelectedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int pos) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So, now I want to transform it to Scala. I think, I should use traits. [SOLVED: In this class I get the error in `onAttach` that `not found: value OnArticleSelectedListener`]:

```
class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    var mListener: OnArticleSelectedListener = null
    ...
    trait OnArticleSelectedListener {
        def onArticleSelected(position: Int)
    }
    ...
    override def onAttach(activity: Activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity)
        mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
    }
    ...
    override def onListItemClick(l: ListView, v: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        // Send the event to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(position);
    }
}
```

In the Activity, I do not know how to "implement" the trait. I know the keyword is "with", but `extends ... with FragmentA.OnArticleSelectedListener` and `extends ... with OnArticleSelectedListener` displays the error `not found: type FragmentA`or `not found: type OnArticleSelectedListener`.

Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, you can cast using `asInstanceOf[Foo]`. In this case, the Scala compiler thinks you are referring to a value called `OnArticleSelectedListener` but cannot find it, because it's not a value but a type. To cast `activity` to an `OnArticleSelectedListener`, you could use this code:

```
activity.asInstanceOf[OnArticleSelectedListener]
```

However, the preferred approach is to use pattern matching as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931463/scala-how-do-i-cast-a-variable). If you take this approach, you could write:

```
mListener = activity match {
    case myActivity: OnArticleSelectedListener => activity
    case _ => throw new ClassCastException 
}
```

I would stick with the `asInstanceOf` in this case, because the semantics are exactly the same and it's more concise.

If you move the definition of `OnArticleSelectedListener` outside of the `FragmentA` class, you should be able to extend it like this:

```
 trait OnArticleSelectedListener { def onArticleSelected(position: Int) }
 class MyActivity extends OnArticleSelectedListener {
   def onArticleSelected(position: Int) { ... }
 }
```

Comment: I had to write: ``case myActivity: OnArticleSelectedListener => myActivity`` otherwise I get the error: ``type mismatch; found : android.app.Activity required: 
 FragmentA.this.OnArticleSelectedListener``

Comment: This sounds like you might have imported the wrong `Activity`.

Comment: Yes, I think, first I had to finish the ``MyActivity``, but I do not know how to "implement" and handle this trait correctly. In Java I can write ``implements FragmentA.OnArticleSelectedListener`` and override the method. In Scala?