# Scala Option[java.util.Date] cannot be cast to Option[java.sql.Date]

Tags: scala, casting, playframework, slick

I have a Play form that looks like this:

```
val form = Form( tuple( 
        /* 5 more fields */ 
        "dueDate" -> optional(date) 
)  )
```

I'm trying to insert `"dueDate"` into an object in Slick.

```
newAuditForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(views.html.error(form)),
    success => {
        Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) withSession {
            Things.forInsert.insert Thing(
                (success._6).asInstanceOf[Option[java.sql.Date]] 
            )
        }
    }
)
```

where Slick only deals with `java.sql.Date`, and Play only deals with `java.util.Date` (?) in the `Form` object.

Using `asInstanceOf` returns:

```
     ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

There's got to be a way for me to write a rule for this cast to be possible ...
would I need to write a [new pattern matching rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931463/how-do-i-cast-a-variable-in-scala/932215#932215)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot cast `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` because `java.sql.Date` is a subclass. What you can do is create a new instance of `java.sql.Date`:

```
val x = new java.util.Date()
val y = new java.sql.Date(x.getTime())
```

You can define an implicit conversion if you consider it useful:

```
implicit def date2sqlDate(d: java.util.Date) = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime())
```

However, this will not convert inside the option (neither will the cast work, because it's not a cast but a conversion).

You can either:

```
val x: Option[java.util.Date]
x.map(_: java.sql.Date) // using implicit conversion
```

Or just write it explicitly:

```
x.map(d => new java.sql.Date(d.getTime()))
```

If you need the conversion very often, you might consider to write an implicit conversion from `Option[java.util.Date]` to `Option[java.sql.Date]`.

Comment: I don't think it is worth introducing implicit conversion if you're already doing explicit map with type ascription.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I appreciate how you went the extra length to explain what was going on. 




Am I right in understanding that explicit conversion is more of a one-time thing, and implicit conversions are equivalent to writing a new type-casting rule?

Comment: @MeredithLeu Welcome. Implicit conversions are special functions used for conversion, not type casting: If you have a value `x: A` and you need a `B` and you have one implicit function `f: A => B` in scope, the compiler will replace `x` by `f(x)`. So on a bytecode-level, they are nothing more than function calls. Explicit conversion is writing the exact same function call yourself. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861501/can-someone-explain-me-implicit-conversions-in-scala

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, I agree. I added this more to show the general mechanism (and prevent confusion with the boxed type). If the conversion is required elsewhere too, it might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Try mapping the `Option[java.util.Date]` to an `Option[java.sql.Date]` like this:

```
(success._6).map(d => new java.sql.Date(d.getTime))
```

One more word of advice, you might want to actually map this to a `java.sql.Timestamp` so you don't lose any time precision when writing it to the DB as I believe will be the case with `java.sql.Date`.  So the code would be:

```
(success._6).map(d => new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of using java.sql.Timestamp instead of Date. I use an Option[Timestamp] elsewhere in my schema, but for this particular object a granularity of day is fine ^.^